# Substitute first string match in 1-line 2GB file on Linux

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed, substitution

I'm trying to substitute only the first match of one string in a huge file with only one line (2.1 GB), this substitution will occur in a shell script job. The big problem is that the machine that will run this script has only 1GB memory (approximately
 300MB free), so i need a buffered strategy that don't overflow my memory. I already tried `sed`, `perl` and a `python` approach, but all of them return me out of memory errors.
Here are my attemps (discovered in other questions):

```
# With perl
perl -pi -e '!$x && s/FROM_STRING/TO_STRING/ && ($x=1)' file.txt

# With sed
sed '0,/FROM_STRING/s//TO_STRING/' file.txt > file.txt.bak

# With python (in a custom script.py file)
for line in fileinput.input('file.txt', inplace=True):
    print line.replace(FROM_STRING, TO_STRING, 1)
    break
```

One good point is that the `FROM_STRING` that i'm searching is always in the beggining of this huge 1-line file, in the first 100 characters. Other good thing is that the execution time is not a problem, it can take time without problems.

**EDIT (SOLUTION):**

I tested three solutions of the answers, all them solved the problem, thanks for all of you. I tested the performance with Linux `time` and all of them take about the same time too, up to 10 seconds approximately... But i choose the @Miller solution because it's simpler (just uses `perl`).

Comment: @AvinashRaj Because the entire file is 1 line, so that will still attempt to load 2 gigs into memory.

Comment: How long is the match string? Is replacement string the same length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're certain the string you're trying to replace is just in the first 100 characters, then the following perl one-liner should work:

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN {$/ = \1024} s/FROM_STRING/TO_STRING/ .. undef' file.txt
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-i`: Edit `<>` files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `BEGIN {$/ = \1024}`: Set the [$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to the number of characters to read for each “line”
- `s/FROM/TO/ .. undef`: Use a [flip-flop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) to perform the regex only once.  Could also have used `if $. == 1`.

Comment: triggers a harmless warning if you enable warnings (which you should, even on oneliners)

Comment: AFAIK `-i` doesn't really edit the file inplace, it makes a copy of it, so will that really work with a 2G file and 1G of memory?

Comment: @Ed Morton, You'll need 4GB of disk space.

Answer (score 6):

Since you know that your string is always in the first chunk of the file, you should use `dd` for this.
You'll also need a temporary file to work with, as in `tmpfile="$(mktemp)"`

First, copy the first block of the file to a new, temporary location:
`dd bs=32k count=1 if=file.txt of="$tmpfile"`

Then, do your substitution on that block:
`sed -i 's/FROM_STRING/TO_STRING/' "$tmpfile"`

Next, concatenate the new first block with the rest of the old file, again using `dd`:
`dd bs=32k if=file.txt of="$tmpfile" seek=1 skip=1`

---

EDIT: As per Mark Setchell's suggestion, I have added a specification of `bs=32k` to these commands to speed up the pace of the `dd` operations. This is tunable, per your needs, but if tuning separate commands distinctly, you may need to be careful about the changes in semantics between different input and output block sizes.

Comment: +1 A good approach, but I would take maybe 32kB off the start and then put the file back together using 32kB chunks because `dd` is often much faster with bigger blocks. Specifically, I mean to add `bs=32k` to your `dd` commands.

Answer (score 1):

- Given that then string to replace is in the first 100 bytes,
- Given that Perl IO is slow unless you start using `sysread` to read large blocks,
- Assuming that the substitution changes the size of the file<sup>[1]</sup>, and
- Assuming that `binmode` isn't needed<sup>[2]</sup>,

I'd use

```
( head -c 100 | perl -0777pe's/.../.../' && cat ) <file.old >file.new
```

---

1. A faster solution for that exists.
2. Though it's easy to add if needed.

Comment: nice; I'd assumed trying to do something like that would result in head discarding a partial block, but it doesn't seem to have that problem.

Comment: @ysth, The original version of my code (as seen in the answer's edit history) would work on systems such as the one you describe.

Comment: FWIW, I saw no speed difference between this answer and mine, though I was doing other stuff on the system at the time.

Comment: Could be my second "given" isn't really given.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I would do:

```
perl -pi -we 'BEGIN{$/=\65536} s/FROM_STRING/TO_STRING/ if 1..1' file.txt
```

to read in 64k chunks.

Comment: Note: That still read from the disk in 8K chunks (or 4K on the older Perls that most people use). Far better performance can be obtained by using `sysread` to actually read large blocks.

Comment: makes almost no difference that I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

A practical (not very compact but efficient) would be to split the file, do the search-replace and join: eg:

```
head -c 100 myfile | sed 's/FROM/TO/' > output.1
tail -c +101 myfile > output.2
cat output.1 output.2 > output && /bin/rm output.1 output.2
```

Or, in one line:

```
( ( head -c 100 myfile | sed 's/FROM/TO/' ) && (tail -c +101 myfile ) ) > output
```

Comment: I wrote an answer very similar to yours before noticing yours. However, mine does far less work to achieve the same result.